android: share variable value outsite a method
I am new to android, so please have mercy!
I have the following code that provide the FCM android token of the device. The variable android_token (as displayed by Log.d) is correct.
Task<String> refreshedToken = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken();
        refreshedToken.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    android_token = task.getResult();
                    Log.d("TAG", "token: " + android_token);
                }
            }
        });

    
Url = "https://www.website.com/index.php?token_FCM=" + android_token;
setWebView();
WebView.loadUrl(Url);

I need a simple way to send it to the Url and display the value on a webview.
How can I create a global variable to do so?

The problem is that android_token won't be set until the asynchronous listener is called.  Making the variable global won't help.  The answer is to put the code to load the webview into the asynchronous listener.  If necessary, add a loading screen to display while waiting for it to finish.

how can be done ? do you have a tutorial ?

@giulia9932 it's about putting your code, where do you form and load URL inside onComplete method, where do you have android_token from task.getResult().
Like this:
if (task.isSuccessful()){
android_token = task.getResult();
Url = "https://www.website.com/index.php?token_FCM=" + android_token;
WebView.loadUrl(Url);
                Log.d("TAG", "token: " + android_token);
            }


thank you for the answer. I did so but the first time the time is opened, the screen stay white for about 30 seconds until the token is generated. The splash screen disappear quite soon and the full user experience is quite bad. how can be solved ?
